# Pre-styling post content to display in lightbox

Tags: custom-post-types, lightbox

So I've built a post system that is pushed into an image grid. When the user clicks on one of the images, a lightbox opens and displays the post content along a feature image via AJAX. Like this: https://code.org/learn

I'm able to get the the post content and the image. However, I would like to be able to pre-stylize them. For example, to be able to push the title in one CSS style, the Categories in other and the content in other to achieve a more designed finish. How do I go about doing this? I'm just realizing that parsing through the post would be out of my scope, and be rather stupid since it would involve a character detection system. But I would like to achieve a well designed solution.

I've built my website on Xtheme and essential grid, the lightbox is the default essential grid one which is fancybox.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean when you say "push the title in one CSS style" Could you clarify?

Comment: @ChessByte by pushing I mean having the ability to take the corresponding post's title (via php perhaps?) and give it a pre-stylized setting in JS. This would happen in the short program that produces the lightbox. `var myAjaxContainer;
window.myAjaxLoaded = function(data) {...};`

Answer (score 0):

Create your own child theme containing a `functions.php` and `style.css` so if your third party theme gets updated, you do not loose any work you put into it.

In the `functions.php` enqueue your stylesheet.

```
function enqueue_my_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'xtheme-custom', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_style' );
```

In your `style.css` write down your CSS mark-up of style adaptions.

Sources:

- [Codex: Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)
- [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: mhmmm, I am not sure this styling would translate into the lightbox. I am gonna try something along these lines.